# How can I view programmatically what resources Qt thinks it has?

Tags: qt, resources

I would like to be able to enumerate the paths to the resources Qt has, for example:

> :/new/prefix/blabla.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Qt can transparently use resources. This means you can like any filesystem use [QDir](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdir.html) to get the contents of any path in the resources -- starting with `:/` will give you the topmost resources folders contents. You can then recursely walk through the folders in the resources (or check the Qt documentation if there is anything already available).

See also the detailed description of `QDir()`: it explicitly states that it can get used with resources.